# При инициализации Vue перестают срабатывать setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, settimeout

В связи с тем что настроек при и инициализации приложения очень много, я это всё раскидал по методам класса:

```js
/**
 * Vue
 */
import Vue from 'vue';
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import VueCookie from 'vue-cookie';
import router from './router/router';

/**
 * Vuex
 */
import store from './store/store';
import {sync} from 'vuex-router-sync';

/**
 * Start layout
 */
import App from './views/layouts/App';

/**
 * и т.д.
 */

/**
 * Приватные свойства
 */

let _is_initial = false;

/**
 * Ссылка
 *
 * @type {null}
 * @private
 */
let _app = null;

let _storage = null;
let _store = null;
let _router = null;
let _cookie = null;
let _echo = null;

export default class Application {

  /**
   * Методы инициализации разных сущностей
   */
  static async initKeysAndHash() {
   // некоторая логика
  }

  static async updateState() {
   // некоторая логика
  }

  static initVue() {

    Vue.use(_cookie);

    sync(_store, _router);

    _app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify,
      store: _store,
      router: _router,
      mixins: [roles_mixin],
      render: h => h(App),
    });

    return Application;
  }

  /**
   * Запуск приложения
   */
  static run() {

    if (!_is_initial) {
      _is_initial = true;

      _storage = new Storage(LocalStorage);
      _store = store;
      _router = router;
      _cookie = VueCookie;
      _echo = Echo;

      Application.initAppPreloader();

      Application.initEcho();

      await Application.initKeysAndHash();

      await Application.updateState();

      Application.initVue();

      setTimeout(() => console.log('test'), 5000 );
    } else {
      throw new Error('The application is already running');
    }
  }

}
```

Запус приложения:

```
/**
 * Start Application
 */
import Application from './Application';

Application.run();
```

Если законсолить `setTimeout()`, то он есть, но не выполняется. Как только я комментриую вызов метода `Application.initVue()`, то таймаут работает. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: наверное в `Application.initVue()` падает исключение.. оберните в try-catch

Comment: Почему вы не хотите воспользоваться стандартным проектом на Vue? [Vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/) отлично генерирует проект и стандартизирует ваш код хоть немного. Я впервые столкнулся с подобным видом проекта и не имею представления даже как вам помочь

Comment: @StrangerintheQ к сожалению нет ошибок, да и если  бы они были `Vue` не проинициализировался бы.

Comment: @MoloF не было времени изучить `vue-cli`, так как помимо того, что я смог обернуть в методы, там куча подключаемых файлов и библиотек. Но чувствую с этим багом придётся пробовать данный инструмент. Но это очень странно...Они ведь как-то отрабатывают?

Comment: @doox911 вам от Vue-cli необходима только пара команд, сначала установите глобально - `npm install -g @vue/cli @vue/cli-service-global` , а затем создайте проект - `vue create <название проекта>` . Данная команда создаст вам проект с необходимым функционалом. Вы сможете на этапе установки выбрать себе необходимые компоненты и включить их в проект автоматически, поэтому это интуитивно понятная надстройка над самим Vue. Попробуйте создать проект так!

Comment: @MoloF зачем этот `@vue/cli-service-global` пакет?

Comment: @doox911 извиняюсь, он не нужен, достаточно первого пакета, второй пакет нужен для прототипирования отдельных компонентов, я не с той страницы скопировал код. Только эта команда нужна - `npm install -g @vue/cli`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111619/discussion-between-doox911-and-molof).